# Debug mongod set breakpoint fail, "No source file named src/mongo/s/request.cpp"

Tags: mongodb, gdb

I have compiled source code for mongodb. I want to debug mongod. I meeted a question. I can set breakpoint in db.cpp, but I can't set breakpoint in request.cpp. I don't understand it. The /home/john/MongoDB2.6.12/mongodb-src-r2.6.12 is project directory, the directory contain src directory, SConstruct file and so on.

```
(gdb) set args --dbpath /home/john/MongoDB2.6.12/mongodb-src-r2.6.12/db_path/
(gdb) pwd
Working directory /home/john/MongoDB2.6.12/mongodb-src-r2.6.12.
(gdb) directory src
Source directories searched: /home/john/MongoDB2.6.12/mongodb-src-r2.6.12/src:/home/john/MongoDB2.6.12/mongodb-src-r2.6.12:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) break src/mongo/db/db.cpp:997
Breakpoint 1 at 0xe3e365: file src/mongo/db/db.cpp, line 997.
(gdb) break src/mongo/s/request.cpp:87
No source file named src/mongo/s/request.cpp.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n
```

Note:
1.The db.cpp belongs to src/mongo/db/.
2.The request.cpp belongs to src/mongo/s/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the root SConscript, it shows request.cpp in mongosLibraryFiles.  It seems you need to debug `mongos` instead of `mongod` if you want to hit that breakpoint.

Comment: rakaiI agree your point.But mongd should do with request, how do  I set breakpoint in request.cpp process(...) methond?

Comment: You can set the breakpoint as pending if the mongos library does get loaded in the future (enterying `y` instead of `n`) but I'm not sure if it will.